# Reusable workflows usage across multiple organizations

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

Consider the below scenario:

- `sample_one` organization has one repository called `one_repo`
- `sample_two` organization has one repository called `two_repo`

`one_repo` has a reusable workflow that needs to be called by `two_repo`, which is in different organization - how do I do this?

The reusable workflow from `one_repo` may be updated from time to time.

Here is the sample code:
my_template.yml (reusable workflow):

```
name: Reusable Workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      config-path:
        required: true
        type: string
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Py
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
            python-version: 3.8

      - name: Install Req
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Run Pytest
        run: |
          echo "Input Value: ${{ inputs.config-path }}"
          pytest
```

test.yml (thats calling the parent workflow that is in different organization):

```
name: Reuse Workflow in current

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  trigger-the_one-workflow:
    uses: parent-org/repo_one/.github/workflows/my_template.yml@main
    with:
      config-path: "qa"
```

Comment: _Most_ of the reusable workflows you use (including GitHub's own  `actions/` ones) are from a different organization, so could you clarify what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

So Basically - I have a workflow file in abc_org/my_abc/.github/workflows/one.yml

I want to call this one.yml in my other organization which is xyz_org/my_xyz/.github/workflows/two.yml

how do I call the one.yml which is in abc organization inside two.yml which is in xyz orgaization?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow

Comment: Yes, I can call the reusable workflow when the repositories are in the "same organization different repository" but I am trying to call the workflow from a different organization.

When I try to call the workflow that belonds to different organization - It says the workflow is not found.

Comment: Then please give a [mre]. If `sample_one/one_repo` is _private_ it won't be accessible from outside the `sample_one` org, otherwise you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe It worked after making the reository as public.

Is there any workaround that I can do so I can keep the parent as private?

I have updated my question with sample code.